# Deleting an accepted answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, vote-to-delete

I gave a [wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24075467/2932052) to a question, but the asker accepted it. I added a second (correct) answer, because completely changing an already accepted answer felt wrong to me. What can be done, if the asker doesn't remove the accept flag?

Comment: *"if the asker doesn't remove the accept flag"* ... nothing

Comment: I've voted to delete it. 2 more 20k+ users and it should disappear. :-)

Comment: It's deleted now.

Comment: @CodyGray and @ kapa thanks for your help! Is this the only way?

Comment: You could potentially flag for moderator attention and explain the situation. But still the easiest is a simple request to the OP to unaccept.

Comment: It's been deleted by the community now.

Comment: "because completely changing an accepted answer felt wrong to me" - I don't understand your reasoning behind that. If your answer is false but already accepted, and OP doesn't respond to a request to un-accept it, changing the accepted answer is infinitely better than having a wrong accepted answer on the site. That said, in this specific case it probably doesn't matter as the question very unlikely to help any future visitors regardless...

Comment: @l4mpi seems true for this special case. But for [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258602/2932052), it was just an example.

Comment: +1 for the desire - and taking action - to curate your content for quality!

Comment: @l4mpi Upvoters and downvoters aren't alerted when an answer is edited, so completely changing it is rather dishonest, especially when it was accepted/highly upvoted.

Comment: @l4mpi, for some silly reason, we think the asker is important and award his or her judgment some special meaning. If that person says a totally wrong answer solved their issue, we have to go with it. It's silly, but those are the rules. If we then change what the user said fixed the problem to something else entirely, we undermine the checkmark and all the silliness that goes along with it.

Comment: I say it would be nice if (a) wholesale changes to an answer automatically invalidated the checkmark or (b) the answerer could simply reject it (perhaps within a *reasonable* timeframe, to prevent coming in months/years later and just rage quitting). I don't know if either has been proposed and/or shot down, however.

Comment: @l4mpi The difference between "improving the answer" and "changing the answer" is that after changing it, the answer won't necessarily still apply to those who upvoted it because it solved their problems.  If you change it, those votes are now a lie.  _Improving_ the answer without changing it does not invalidate those votes.  wheaties' answer is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Izkata that reasoning implies that the new answer does not solve the problem anymore, which seems unlikely. You're also implying all upvotes come from people with a similar problem who found the answer helpful, not just from random users who upvote a seemingly plausible but wrong answer. But I think we're mostly on the same page here - if the wrong answer contained helpful content, this should not be deleted by an edit unless it would become redundant (and given it is on-topic and related to the question, of course).

Comment: WHAT? How can a accepted answer be deleted? In some other Meta post I red that "an accepted answer can't be deleted .. not even by Moderator". Then how this deletion was made possible?

Comment: @Rahul Users with 20k+ reputation and moderators can delete any answer, regardless of whether it is accepted. What they *cannot* do is remove the accept checkmark or switch it to another answer. Only the person who asked the question can do that.

Comment: @CodyGray, Thanks for the info. I am approaching towards that :)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you have the ability to edit your answer then...

> *Disclaimer as to why the original answer is wrong*
>
> **Correct Answer**
>
> blah blah blah
>
> **Previous Answer**
>
> blah blah blahty blah

That's what I'd do so that people who come to it (especially the person who asked) knows that the accepted answer was wrong and *why*. *Why* is very important

Comment: I like this option far better; Deleting your old answer removes the data, which might be interesting to see for archives sake.

Comment: This is exactly what I do, usually when OP adds some information regarding her question or comments on some specific aspect of my answer +1

Comment: You don't necessarily have to actually leave the previous answer in - it's always still available via edit history.  Just mention that you changed it and why, and specifically reference the edit history link.

Comment: I think it's useful to leave the old answer in so people can easily see what was accepted.  Sometimes people are wrong about being wrong.

Comment: This is what I was going to answer with when I saw the question.  And agreed with leaving the original in the body of the text rather than relegating it to the edit history (unless the change is fairly minor).  Convincing incorrect answers, so long as there is an actual correction, can be very informative.

Comment: Keeping the old potentially incorrect answer & revising your post to also include a new updated answer ensures any comments made during the old answer will still hold their value, rather than seeming irrelevant if the new answer voids any comments.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same once, then I flagged my answer as "Other" and explained, Moderator "unaccepted" my answer, then I deleted my own answer.

So the easiest way is to flag your answer as "Other" and explain, leave the rest for moderator.

Comment: @whe Yes, this is a good option, if the correct answer is already given by another one (+1). But in cases like mine, I now think it's better to follow [wheaties's suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258638/2932052)

Comment: I just wanted to add my situation, otherwise I too support wheaties's answer :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that moderators can't unaccept your answer, unless it is *their question*. They can delete it, of course.

Comment: happened to me, don't know how.

Comment: Moderators cannot 'unaccept' an answer. If your answer was unaccepted, it was done by the OP themselves. Moderators can only delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once. I realized that it was no doubt at all that the answer was wrong, and also was misleading to future readers. I edited the answer to something like:

> This answer was wrong, but I cannot delete because it is accepted

and then I reported it.

Comment: Consider if [the solution explained by wheaties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258638/2932052) would be better. I personally found it best, but of course it depends also on the presence of competing answers ...